# How not to show specific values from a directory using glob?

Tags: python

**My Goal:**

Current goal for me is to return values that don't contain the value `test.docx`

**My Current code:**

I have this code here:

```
    # Create a Tkinter variable
    self.tkvar = StringVar()

    # Directory
    self.directory = "C:/Users/label/Desktop/Sign off project/test only/to sign"
    self.choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.directory, "*")) #all choices
```

**What it does:**

That gives me all file names inside a specific folder. How can I add a condition not to return me values that end with `"test.docx"`

**Would your answer depend on the following code?**

I have this code here, it's a `OptionMenu` / drop down menu of values in `tkinter`.

I have added this in, as I believe the code may be slightly different when working with drop down menu's

```
self.popupMenu = OptionMenu(main, self.tkvar, *self.choices) # Dropdown menu of all files inside the folder
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using list comprehension:

```
# Create a Tkinter variable
self.tkvar = StringVar()

# Directory
self.directory = "C:/Users/label/Desktop/Sign off project/test only/to sign"
self.choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.directory, "*")) #all choices
# list comprehension to filter 
self.choices = [f for f in self.choices if 'test.docx' not in f]
```

This would remove any elements from self.choices that contain 'test.docx'

Comment: I like the fact that it is "containing" rather than "ending" with! Do you know any research material, where I can properly study and understand this? Thanks

Comment: Hi, just realized... I am unpacking `self.choices`, I require it to be a listlike

Comment: What about files like "*c:\test.docx.bak*"?

Answer (score 1):

you can always `filter` the results of glob:

```
    # Create a Tkinter variable
    self.tkvar = StringVar()

    # Directory
    self.directory = "C:/Users/label/Desktop/Sign off project/test only/to sign"
    self.choices = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.directory, "*")) #all choices
    self.choices = list(filter(lambda x: not x.endswith("test.docx"), self.choices))
```

the filter returns a generator, so you might want to convert it to a `list`, depending on what you're doing with it.

edit: I saw that you are unpacking `self.choices`, this does require it to be a listlike

Comment: Hi, instead if ending with, is it possible to show `containing`?

Comment: What about files like "*c:\dummy\_test.docx*"?

Comment: @98Ed yes, replace `not x.endswith("test.docx")` with `"test.docx" not in x`

Comment: @CristiFati this solution will filter out files which end with the string "test.docx", like the name you mentioned.  You may need to change the directory variable if the file is in the root "c:\\" directory.